# How do I compare pairs of elements in a single array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an assignment where I'm asked to take a string, explode it into an array, and then compare every two values of said array. They said we should you use the array_shift() function to take the first value of the array and compare it to the "new" first element. So basically, we have to compare [0] with [1], [2] with [3], and so on. For a more visual representation, this is what I have so far:

```
/*Constant*/
define("STRING_END", 7);

/*This functions prints two domino tiles; it's not really part of the question.*/
    function printTiles($left, $right){
        echo "<img src='".$left."_.png'/>", "<img src='_".$right.".png'/>";
    }

    /* Main Algorithm */
    $text = "1,2,4,4,4,6,7"; //the goal is to check if every two elements of the string are the same
    $arrayedText= explode(",", $text); //now I have the array with all the numbers from the string

    $doubleTiles = false; //this is just to check when double tiles have been found

    while ($arrayedText[1] != STRING_END){ //so while the next position is not a "7"
        $firstTile = array_shift($arrayedText); //the first tile is the first element of the array
        $nextTile = $arrayedText[0];        //the next tile is the "new" first element of the array after having removed the other one
        if($firstTile == $nextTile){ //if these two tiles are the same
            $doubleTiles = true; 
            printTiles($firstTile, $nextTile); //run the function and print the tiles on screen
        }
    }
```

So the issue I'm  having is that it's basically comparing [0] with [1] and checking if they're the same, which is fine. But then it's checking [1] and [2] and checking if they're the same. Meaning that it's going to compare [3] and [4] and detect it as a double pair; which wouldn't be correct. I basically want a way to skip to the next pair of numbers.

Hopefully I've managed to get my point/question across. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are after finding doubles in your string or exploded array, we could shift twice and then compare for equality.  We stop if either of shifts return null (null implies empty or not an array).

```
<?php

$items = [1,2,4,4,4,6,7];

while
(
       ($a = array_shift($items)) !== null
    && ($b = array_shift($items)) !== null
) {
    if($a == $b)
        echo 'Double: ', $a, ' ', $b, "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
 Double: 4 4
```

Comment: This is much more efficient! The only thing I've changed is the "null" part. The assignment has some assumed prerequisites and conditions, one of them being that the string will never have null values and that they will always end with the number 7. 

Thanks a lot @Progrock!

Comment: You could reduce the condition to  `($a = array_shift($items)) && ($b = array_shift($items))`, but, that depends on 'truthy' values in your string.  If you had the digit `0` it would not match the condition, as `0 && 2` is false, so the loop would end.  You have to be very careful.  Checking against null is more robust.  Always check the reference for a functions return.  If array_shift returns null, it could imply an empty array, not an array, or a `null` being shifted from the array.

Answer (score 0):

After you check your shifted item against the new first item of the array you need to shift again to advance for the next pair check:

```
<?php
function are_all_pairs(array $items) {
    $count = count($items);
    if($count == 0 || $count % 2 !== 0)
        return false; // Empty or uneven input array.

    while(($shifted = array_shift($items)) !== null) {
        if($shifted !== $items[0])
            return false;
        array_shift($items);
    }

    return true;
}

var_dump(
    are_all_pairs([2,2,2,1]),
    are_all_pairs([2,2,4,4,3,3])
);
```

Output:

```
bool(false)
bool(true)
```

However I could get a false positive with an input such as [2,2,null,null,2,1] for the above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The thing is, we needed to avoid using any additional functions. It's a very basic PHP programming course. So they sometimes make us solve problems in a very inefficient way. But I think I finally figured it out!

Thanks again!

Comment: I tried to keep it in the spirit of your original, shifting and comparing to the new first item.  The only extra function here is `count`.

Comment: But, given a non-empty array, an array with an even number of items, and non-null values, you could skip the 'guard', and bypass that count.

Comment: This one is slightly more resistant and has no functions other than `array_shift` (and itself), it's resistant to null entries, and ignores keys, so is fine for associative arrays : https://3v4l.org/QO9bi

Comment: I misinterpreted the question here from your comment in your code 'the goal is to check if every two elements of the string are the same'

Answer (score 0):

I think I actually figured out how to do it without using any additional functions (as specified by the assignment).

```
/*Constant*/
define("STRING_END", 7);

/*This functions prints two domino tiles; it's not really part of the question.*/
    function printTiles($left, $right){
        echo "<img src='".$left."_.png'/>", "<img src='_".$right.".png'/>";
    }

    /* Main Algorithm */
    $text = "1,2,4,4,4,6,7"; //the goal is to check if every two elements of the string are the same
    $arrayedText= explode(",", $text); //now I have the array with all the numbers from the string
    $firstTile = array_shift($arrayedText); //the first tile is the first element of the array
    $doubleTiles = false; //this is just to check when double tiles have been found

    while ($firstTile != STRING_END){ //so while the next position is not a "7"
        if($firstTile == $arrayedText[0]){ //if these two tiles are the same
            $doubleTiles = true; 
            printTiles($firstTile, $arrayedText[0]); //run the function and print the tiles on screen
        }
        $firstTile = array_shift($arrayedText);
        $firstTile = array_shift($arrayedText);  
    }
```

So basically I just needed to array shift twice after checking if the first tile and the first position of the array were equal. This way, it would skip on to the next pair. I also needed to make the While loop break when the first tile was "7".

It took some testing, but I figured it out!

Comment: No other functions you now say.  `define`, `printTiles`, `explode` all look like additional functions to `array_shift`.

Comment: `array_shift` returns the shifted value, or NULL if array is empty or is not an array.  If you do not have null values, you can use that as a conditional test.  Saves the need for the define line which is quite inflexible.